# Timestamp conversion in Time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to R, trying to analyse a time series data from HVAC sensor. The data in in the following format. Do I need to convert it to a ts() object before staring any analysis or can I gp ahead with the same below are the results found:

```
 Time | Value
1 7/6/16 4:45|28
2 7/8/16 4:51|31
3 7/6/16 5:10|26
4 7/6/16 5:10|26
5 7/6/16 5:11|26
6 7/6/16 5:11|26

str(dataset)
data.frame':    628 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Time : chr  "7/6/16 4:45" "7/8/16 4:51" "7/6/16 5:10" "7/6/16 5:10" ...
 $ Value: int  28 31 26 26 26 26 26 27 29 29 ...
```

Now do I need to change the time format from character to any other format? When I am running the following code:

```
dataset$Time=as.POSIXct(as.character(dataset$Time),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

the time is becoming `NA` in the dataset.

Thanks
Dwiti

Comment: your format is wrong. Should be `%d/%m/%y %H:%M`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you have date in m/d/y format)

```
dataset$Time = strptime(as.character(dataset$Time),format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
head(dataset$Time,3)
[1] "2016-07-06 04:45:00 IST" "2016-07-08 04:51:00 IST" "2016-07-06 05:10:00 IST"
```

Comment: Hi sandipan,even this is causeing the same issue <NA> values under time column

Comment: i have removed stringsAsFactors=FALSE while loading the file and now dataset$Time = strptime(as.character(dataset$Time),format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
is giving me following result                 Time Value
1 2016-07-06 04:45:00    28
2 2016-07-08 04:51:00    31
3 2016-07-06 05:10:00    26
4 2016-07-06 05:10:00    26
5 2016-07-06 05:11:00    26
6 2016-07-06 05:11:00    26
> now my question is do i have to convert this into ts() before any other analysis or i can simply go ahead with this

Comment: depends on what you want to do with the timestamps

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response and guidance sandipan, really appreciate your help. I am dealing with sensor data that is captured in seconds with temperature, humidity and light intensity measures.

Comment: what kind of analysis do u want to do on your time series data? is it prediction?

Comment: Hi Sandipan, so i have a dataset that is coming out of a HVAC sensor, its a RnD project. So all I am trying to do is trying to give some analytical insight to the team, it could be predictive as well, however, as of now the data is simulated so im not sure how good it will be for prediction.It is however a stationary series

Answer (score 0):

We can use compact option `mdy_hm` from `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
dataset$Time <- mdy_hm(dataset$Time)
dataset$Time
#[1] "2016-07-06 04:45:00 UTC" "2016-07-08 04:51:00 UTC"
#[3] "2016-07-06 05:10:00 UTC" "2016-07-06 05:10:00 UTC"
#[5] "2016-07-06 05:11:00 UTC" "2016-07-06 05:11:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
dataset <- structure(list(Time = c("7/6/16 4:45", "7/8/16 4:51", "7/6/16 5:10", 
"7/6/16 5:10", "7/6/16 5:11", "7/6/16 5:11"), Value = c(28L, 
31L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L)), .Names = c("Time", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: i have used the following code in lubridate package library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(dataset$Time) but got All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: @DwitiB  It is based on your example and in my code I am using `mdy_hm` and not `ymd_hms` as you showed in the comments.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, however, the dataset that you created looks like manually entering the value which is technically a challenge for the dataset that i already have, in that case how do i modify it to make sure that R reads the timestamp correctly

Comment: @DwitiB The dataset I created is based on the `dput` output.  It gives the structure of the data.  In your post, there was no indication about the column types.